# Making birthday function for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make birthday function that suppose to pull informations from database and give name, surname etc. of person that is bithday on that day.Am I on a good way? I make something like this:

```
<?php

function birthday($year){


extract(shortcode_year(array('how_many_days'=>'1'),$year));
require('./wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;

for($i=0; $i<=$how_many_days; $i++)
{

$day = $i*24*60*60;

for($j=18; $j<=75; $j++){

$past_day=mktime(0,0,0, date(n,time()), date(j,time()), date(Y, time()) - $j) + $day;

$results=$wpdb>get_results("SELECT first_name, last_name, date_birthday,private_id, responsible FROM wp_participants_database WHERE date_birthday=$past_day");

foreach($results as $result): $brojac=$brojac+1;

echo '<TR><TD align=right>', $j, 'ans:', $result->first_name, '</TD><TD><B>',
$result->last_name, '<B></TD><TD>', $result->private_id, date(Y,$result->date_birthday),"/", 
date(m, $result->date_birthday), "/", date(d, $result->date_birthday),'</TD></TR>=>', $result->responsible,'<br/>';
endforeach;    

   }
  }
 }

add_shortcode('birthday', 'birthday');

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you are missing `->` in this line

```
$results=$wpdb>get_results("SELECT first_name, last_name, date_birthday,private_id, responsible FROM wp_participants_database WHERE date_birthday=$past_day");
```

It should be like this

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT first_name, last_name, date_birthday,private_id, responsible FROM wp_participants_database WHERE date_birthday=$past_day");
```